# C# - Parse part of a list into another list for parsing then adding to a new list for display

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I hope the title was adequate. I also hope I can word this properly to explain what I am trying to do.

This is a Xamarin Forms app using an SQLite DB.

I have a database, in the table, I'm adding stats for my local pool league.

Player model:

```
 public class Players
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int EntryId { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int GamesWon { get; set; }
        public int GamesLost { get; set; }
        public int GamesPlayed { get; set; }
        public decimal Average { get; set; }
        public int WeekNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

I add entries every week, The data is inserted in the following way The `GamesPlayed` and `Average` are calculated before the insertion and the rest are from UI.

What I am attempting to do is get all of the rows from the Players table, currently, there are  2 players, the player with Id 1 has 8 rows, and the player with id 2 has 2 rows.

I am trying to iterate through the player's list to add the data, `GamesWon`, and `GamesLost`, and then add the consolidated data to a new list to display on the screen.

```
public async Task<List<Players>> ConsolidatePlayer()
        {
            Players playerTotals = new Players();
            var players = await playerService.GetAllPlayersAsync();

            if (players.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in players)
                {
                    
                    var getPlayerData = await playerService.GetAllBySingleId(item.Id);

                    if (getPlayerData != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var single in getPlayerData)
                        {
                            playerTotals.Id = single.Id;
                            playerTotals.Name = single.Name;
                            playerTotals.GamesWon += single.GamesWon;
                            playerTotals.GamesLost += single.GamesLost;
                            playerTotals.GamesPlayed = playerTotals.GamesWon + playerTotals.GamesLost;
                            playerTotals.Average = Decimal.Round((decimal)(playerTotals.GamesWon / (decimal)playerTotals.GamesPlayed) * 100, 2);
                            playerTotals.WeekNumber = single.WeekNumber;
                        }
                    }

                    pList.Add(playerTotals);
                }

            }
            return pList;
        }
```

The issue I am encountering is when the `playerTotals` are added to the list it is being added for each row in `getPlayerData`, so Player with Id 1 is added 8 times and so on.

I have tried implementing a counter to compare with the count of `getPlayerData` and add once they are equal, but then I ended up with only 1 entry in pList and it was for the player with id 2.

Comment: you are reusing the same `playerTotals` over and over instead creating a new one for reach player.  There may be other problems with your code, but that's the first thing I see wrong with it

Comment: I have changed it now and it will create a new playerTotals each time.

Comment: did that fix the problem?  You really need to just step through the code in the debugger and see if it is actually behaving the way you think it is

Comment: While stepping through I think I figured it out,

the players list I get from the database contains 10 rows
When I am looping through that it goes through 10 times. 

What I need to do is figure out how to get just distinct playerIds with SQLite, this way it will have 1 row per player in the players list and then pull the appropriate number of rows for each playerId to consolidate the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help. With the comments and the one answer I was able to get to the result.

The things I was doing wrong were, not creating a new playerTotals each time. I had my pList.Add in the wrong spot and when I was initially pulling the data I was pulling all records causing it to loop too many times. Below is the modified code that is now working properly.
`

```
    public async Task<List<Players>> ConsolidatePlayer()
        {
            var pList = new List<Players>();
            var players = await playerService.GetDistinctPlayerId();

            if (players.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in players)
                {
                    Players playerTotals = new Players();
                    var getPlayerData = await playerService.GetAllBySingleId(item);

                    if (getPlayerData != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var single in getPlayerData)
                        {
                            playerTotals.Id = single.Id;
                            playerTotals.Name = single.Name;
                            playerTotals.GamesWon += single.GamesWon;
                            playerTotals.GamesLost += single.GamesLost;
                            playerTotals.GamesPlayed = playerTotals.GamesWon + playerTotals.GamesLost;
                            playerTotals.Average = Decimal.Round((decimal)(playerTotals.GamesWon / (decimal)playerTotals.GamesPlayed) * 100, 2);
                            playerTotals.WeekNumber = single.WeekNumber;
                        }
                    }

                    pList.Add(playerTotals);
                }

            }
            return pList;
       }
```

`

Comment: Also reference for you in the future. Try to NEVER name your objects in their plural naming. This is a best practice that is followed by most people.

Comment: Thank you. I will take this into future projects. I have 0 formal education in programming. I will accept my answer once I can, which is in 23 hours